# Get Preceding Line & Following Line for an UPPERCASEWORD

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

String `S` looks like this:

```
S = "HOLY CROWS \n This looks scary. \n Horror score rises. \n MAYBE I should ask \n STACKOVERFLOW \n They would know."
```

Desired Output:

> "I should ask STACKOVERFLOW They would know."

Basically:

Find every match that has single upper-case words that are wrapped in following conditions:

- Get string after UPPERCASEWORD until line-break.
- Get string preceding UPPERCASEWORD until ANOTHERUPPERCASEWORD is encountered, if and only if, no line-breaks were found in between.

Here's what I have so far:

```
\w\n\w[A-Z]+\n.*?\w
```

But this doesn't conquer the complete line before and after the word.
Neither does it fulfill the second requirement.

Current Output:

> "k STACKOVERFLOW T"

Comment: Try [`[A-Z]{2}.*\r?\n.*[A-Z]{2}.*\r?\n.*`](https://regex101.com/r/hw4LxQ/1). I assume you would like to match ALLCAPS that are at least 2 letters long. Else, try [`\b[A-Z]+\b.*\r?\n.*\b[A-Z]+\b.*\r?\n.*`](https://regex101.com/r/hw4LxQ/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
(?:^|\r?\n)(.*?)\r?\n([A-Z]+)r?\n(.*?)(?:\r?\n|$)
```

And get the following groups:

```
$1 $2 $3
```

This will match any uppercase word, directly preceded and followed by a line break. Everything before the first line break and after the last line break will be inside the group.

- `(?:)` matches a group without being numbered (like `$1`, `$2`)
- `.*?` matches 0 or more characters lazily (non-greedy)
- `\r?\n` matches a Windows `\r\n` and UNIX `\n` linebreak
- `^` and `$` start and end of string

*Here is a [live example](https://regex101.com/r/6TGfKZ/1)*.